# Should I use interface or abstract base class defining List functionalities

Tags: c#, oop, dependency-injection

I have a basic list functionalities:

```
Add(object)  
GetAll()  
Count()
```

In my current assignment I need to inject this list object into another object that will be using it.

I also only want to implement the in memory version of it at this point, but want to leave it open to some day maybe implement database implementation of it.

Would one use interface to define the above functions or abstract base class ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An abstract base class is a means of sharing implementation, of an interface, between multiple concrete classes.

However, since clients should never care about implementation details, the dependency injection should always be through an interface. Otherwise the clients are imposing a choice of implementation upon the dependency, which is exactly the type of coupling that DOI is intended to prevent.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to provide some default functionality for all derived class in future then abstract class would be great else interface and also those abstract classes are also helpful in case of modification to project if you plan to modify base class because you can define that functionality in base class and automatically all inheriting classes will have same functionality without disturbing structure. Hope it helps!